# Need help to identify a 1x6 support or wall piece

Tags: piece-information

I have looked through pick a brick to find it. I even went searched up the specific set for it but still can't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is [Support 1 x 6 x 5 Girder Rectangular (64448)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/64448/support-1-x-6-x-5-girder-rectangular/).

[image: LDraw part render in blue]

The element ID for this is hard to make out in the photo, but it is 6186296.

PaB won't have all elements, especially if they aren't currently in production. This element hasn't been used in a set since 2020. It was last used in the Saturn V remake that is no longer in production.

You can search by element ID on other sites such as [Brickset](https://brickset.com/search?query=6186296), [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/search/?q=6186296), or [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=6186296) to lookup information about a given element ID.